# Get height of a hidden, dynamically populated UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios8

I am trying to get a "screenshot" of a specific UIView that gets loaded from a xib that is never to be seen by the user.

Here's the code:

```
let nibViews = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: ownedBy, options: nil)
if let cardView = nibViews.first as? CardView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cardView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    cardView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(cardView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let imageAgain = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
//do something with image
```

The issue I'm having is that the cardView bounds, when I pass them into the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, are not correct. Specifically the height is not correct. If i println(cardView.bounds.size.height) before UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, I get a generic "600" for the height... which distorts the image that gets created.

I did find a "solution", but not something I'm feeling comfortable with - if I call the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions code block TWICE, on the second pass, the cardView.bounds.size.height returns the CORRECT height based on the content added to the cardView (also taking into account the constraints on the xib)

What seems to be happening is, the cardView's true layout isn't fully realized until drawViewHierarchyInRect is called once.

My question is - what is drawViewHierarchyInRect doing to make cardView report the correct height? And can I somehow do that thing through some separate function without creating 2 screenshots of the UIView?

Comment: The problem is that your view controller's subviews have had a chance to layout  in relation to a view since they haven't been added to a view. What happens if you try adding cardView.view.layoutSubviews() at start of the if block?

Comment: Actually... I suggest adding loadNibNamed as a subview but hiding it  so that it has an opportunity to layout its subviews in accordance to the view.

Comment: I've tried both already. Adding cardView to a subview DOES do something... it does return a height different than 600, it returns a height of 58, but the real height of the card is actually 341. So, that distorts it in a different way.

Comment: Oh, so is CardView a view controller or something else? How are you setting its height? In a storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: cardView is a UIView that is loaded from a xib. In that xib file, I have a series of different constraints that affect the layout.